# No graphical user interface

Tags: upgrade, gui, tty

I tried to upgrde on from ubuntu mate 16.04 to 18.04.
Since then when it startup it goes to tty1 instead of loading gui.

Comment: When i tried to launch startx first it came with an error message about permission problem with accessing dev/fb0. Then i tried to sudo launch it. Since it waits a long while and drops a timeout message with xauth and blanks the screen and nothing happens.